# CSS3 hovering out transition effect

Tags: css-transitions

Hello guys im having a hard time configuring out what is the missing part of my css, because the animation in hover out is not the same in hover in, here is the fiddle link thank you.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/m2Lz4euv/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the timing properties in the not-hover selectors.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2Lz4euv/5/)

What I've done is changing this:

```
.hamburger-wrap span:first-of-type {
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger-wrap:hover span:first-of-type{
   top: 12px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-property: top, transform;
  transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  transition-delay: 0s, .1s;
}
```

To this:

```
.hamburger-wrap span:first-of-type {
  top: 0;
  transition-property: top, transform;
  transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  transition-delay: 0s, .1s;
}

.hamburger-wrap:hover span:first-of-type{
   top: 12px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

If you want different timing for the in- and out state you can set the in-timing in the :hover selector and the out-timing in the regular selector.

Answer (score 0):

[HOVER FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/dtyjzgvp/2/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

/* Icon 1 */

#nav-icon1, #nav-icon2, #nav-icon3, #nav-icon4 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon1 span, #nav-icon3 span, #nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon1:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#nav-icon1:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}

#nav-icon1:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}


/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon3:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3:hover span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

/* Icon 4 */

#nav-icon4 {
}

#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon4:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -3px;
  left: 8px;
}

#nav-icon4:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon4:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 39px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-icon1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div id="nav-icon3">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="nav-icon4">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```